# List view search bar: some fields aren’t searchable and tool tip shows you the list of unsearchable fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

Depending on the object you view, certain fields aren’t searchable, but you can still** **filter ****or sort on those fields. Want to see which fields aren’t searchable? Place your cursor in the list view search box and a tool tip shows you the list of unsearchable fields.

my Question is : is there any way or customization  to search nonsearcherable fields instead of using filter?

Thanks,

I googled it and find this "The native search functionality in Salesforce, including the limitations on searchable fields, is built into the platform and cannot be directly modified or changed by users."

however is there any solutions you can recommend me?